# Excel Vba - Group number sequence inside a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which returns a string of numeric sequence of all matching value from a defined cell.
Illustration as per below:

```
COL A    COL B  COL C
Item No  Data   Unique Data
1        A      A
2        A      B
3        A
4        B
5        B
6        A
7        A
8        B
9        B
10       B
```

Cell D2 = Lookupsequence(C2,B2:B11,A2:A11) will return `1, 2, 3, 6, 7`

Cell D3 = Lookupsequence(C3,B2:B11,A2:A11) will return `4, 5, 8, 9, 10`

However, the result I want is;

Cell D2 -> `1-3, 6-7`

Cell D3 -> `4-5, 8-10`

Below is the Code of the function I'm using:

```
Function Lookupsequence(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) = Search_string Then
result = result & ", " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value

End If
Next
Lookupsequence = Trim(result)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function Lookupsequence(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim initial As String
Dim separator As String
Dim preValue As Integer
Dim value As Integer

preValue = -1
separator = ""
For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
    value = CInt(Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).value)
    If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) = Search_string Then
        If value - 1 = preValue Then
            result = initial & "-" & value
        Else
            result = result & separator & value
            initial = result
            separator = ","
        End If
        preValue = value
    End If
Next
Lookupsequence = Trim(result)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks SkyMaster, It's just the way I want it to be. Furthermore your code seems to work much faster compared to the old one. Thank you very much..