# Group number sequence inside a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and learning myself...
I am facing a similar problem with this post: [Excel Vba - Group number sequence inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351363/excel-vba-group-number-sequence-inside-a-string)

which the difference is that my item no. is in horizontal like below:

```
ColA(ID) ColB ColC ColD ColE ColF ColG
A        101  102  103     
B        201  202  203  501  502
```

Sometimes for an ID, there will only have 3 item no., sometimes with 5, they can be upto 30 sometimes...

What I think the function could look like this: Cell G1 = lookupsequence(A1:A30), since that lookup function is no need in this situtation

Then G1 -> `101-103`
Then G2 -> `201-203, 501-502`

Below is the code I have based on that post, but just generating G1: `101, 102, 103`

```
Lookupsequence(Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim initial As String
Dim separator As String
Dim preValue As Integer
Dim value As Integer

preValue = -1
separator = ""
For i = 1 To 30
    value = CInt(Return_val_col.Cells(1, i).value)
        If value - 1 = preValue Then
            result = initial & "-" & value
        Else
            result = result & separator & value
            initial = result
            separator = ","
        End If
Next
Lookupsequence = Trim(result)
End Function
```

I tried to add something like but not succeed

```
Dim lastcol As Long
lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lastcol
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a max of 30 numbers within the limits of rownumbers of Excel, try:

```
Function GetSequence(rng1 As Range) As String

Dim rng2 As Range
For Each cl In rng1.SpecialCells(2, 1)
    If rng2 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = Cells(cl.Value, 1)
    Else
        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, Cells(cl.Value, 1))
    End If
Next

GetSequence = Replace(Replace(rng2.Address(False, False), "A", ""), ":", "-")

End Function
```

Invoke through: `=GetSequence(B1:D1)` or whichever range holding the numbers.

---

If numbers get too large and too many for the above function, try:

```
Function GetSequence(rng As Range) As String

Dim arr As Variant: arr = rng.Value

With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each el In arr
        If IsNumeric(el) And el <> "" Then .Add el
    Next
    
    .Sort
    For i = .Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If i = .Count - 1 Then
            GetSequence = .Item(i) & "|"
        Else
            If Val(GetSequence) = .Item(i) + 1 Then
                If Mid(GetSequence, Len(.Item(i)) + 1, 1) = "-" Then
                    GetSequence = .Item(i) & Mid(GetSequence, Len(CStr(Val(GetSequence))) + 1)
                Else
                    GetSequence = .Item(i) & "-" & GetSequence
                End If
            Else
                GetSequence = .Item(i) & "," & GetSequence
            End If
        End If     
    Next
End With

GetSequence = Replace(GetSequence, "|", "")

End Function
```

It's abit verbose but this way can even insert empty or unsorted arrays of numbers:

[image]

Comment: Hi JvdV, Thank you so much for providing the answer so quickly! It works like a charm! Just 1 thing... I found that if the number exceed 6 digit, the results will become #Value...since my number are in 9 digit, is there any way to solve it too? Thanks again for the above reply !

Comment: @excelquestion11, no, this answer would only work with the assumption the numeric values won't exceed the last possible rownumber in your excel-version. For me that would be 1048576.

Comment: oh...that is really sad to hear that, anyway, still appreciate your effort!

Comment: You don't need to accept the answer untill you find the most usefull one to your question. There are other ways to do this for sure @excelquestion11. I might come up with one later if no-one else does.

Comment: Man...this is beautiful! Your code works nicely in my sheet for large no. which up to 9 digits, you saved me lol Thanks again, and I am happy to receive all the helps as this is my first post :D @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and it worked correctly for me. I returned to the page and saw the solution from JvdV; so I thought I'd post my solution too.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()

Dim result$
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

result$ = Lookupsequence(WS.Range("B1:AE1"))
result$ = Lookupsequence(WS.Range("B2:AE2"))
result$ = Lookupsequence(WS.Range("B3:AE3"))

End Sub

Private Function Lookupsequence(Return_val_col As Range) As String

Dim preValue%, value%
Dim i&
Dim result$, separator$

preValue = -1
result = ""
separator = ", "
For i = 1 To Return_val_col.count
    value = CInt(Return_val_col.Cells(1, i).value)
    
    If value = 0 Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf result = "" Then
        result = value
    ElseIf value - 1 <> preValue Then
        result = result & "-" & preValue & separator & value
    End If
    
    preValue = value
Next

If value = 0 Then
    value = preValue
End If

result = result & "-" & value

Lookupsequence = Trim(result)

End Function
```

My test data in two images from columns A to AE to test the possibility of 30 item numbers

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cyrus! This also works and I love how you improve the code based on mine so that I can have more understanding about what's the problem of my code :D